# Shadow on UIButton text only (not background)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, shadow

I have a set of `UIButton`s with background colors. when the user taps one, I want **only** the button's text to have a shadow all around it (to show that it has been selected). However, when I add the shadow, the shadow appears over the whole button (background and all), and not just the text. Is there an easier workaround to this than just adding a `UILabel` over a blank button?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
...
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[button.layer setShadowRadius:8.0];
[button.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]];
[button.layer setShadowOpacity:0];
...
```

Comment: What you actually want, When you tap, button text should look with shadow, and background should remain same?

Comment: To add shadow to the text, take a look at [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html)

Comment: @Viral The text should have a shadow, and the background should not.

Comment: @luk2302 How, exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the simple way to add shadow to the button title with shadow radius property available in Objective-C:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>    

button.titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
button.titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:0.7].CGColor;
button.titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
button.titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
button.titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Swift ..

Say you override the `UIButton` class ..

```
    titleLabel!.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    titleLabel!.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -0.5, height: 0.5)
    titleLabel!.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    titleLabel!.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    titleLabel!.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: thanks so much, @Userich!  By coincidence you posted this just as I needed it.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the shadow on the `titleLabel` property of the `UIButton` rather than what you're doing now.

eg

```
button.titleLabel.shadowColor = ((selectionState) ?[UIColor orangeColor] : [UIColor clearColor] );
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (1.5,1.5);
```

---

## For 2018

This does not work.  Use the answer of @Userich

Comment: This no longer works.  Will now add a general area shadow that isn't specifically tied to the text.  Now need to use: setTitleShadowColor, etc

Answer (score 2):

You need to use *setTitleShadowColor: forState:* and *shadowOffset* property of *UIButton*.
below code will add shadow only to button label whenever user tap on button.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 70, 200, 100);

[button setTitle:@"Test Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:45]];

[button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[button.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use attributed strings for the normal and highlighted titles. You can create an `NSShadow` object, and assign that as the value for the `NSShadowAttributeName`. This gives you control over the properties of the shadow. To keep the title from dimming, you should set the button type to `Custom` instead of `System`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2;

    NSString *titleString = @"Title";
    NSAttributedString *normalTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titleString];
    NSAttributedString *highlightedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titleString attributes:@{NSShadowAttributeName:shadow}];

    [self.button setAttributedTitle:normalTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setAttributedTitle:highlightedTitle forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```